# Gunicorn workers timing out after SSL install (Django, Nginx)

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https, gunicorn

After a bit of a struggle to set up AWS Route53 IPv6 and my DSN (Ionos) I've managed to set up SSL in my Django blog app running with Gunicorn and nginx.
I've used this [tutorial](https://medium.com/techkylabs/django-deployment-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-with-postgresql-nginx-ssl-e6504a02f224)

Unfortunately, first it ran into the redirect loop error that I managed to fix but now it's 502 Bad Gateway and when I check the logs it looks like Gunicorn workers are alway timing out. I tried setting the timeout to 300s for both nginx and Gunicorn but it just means a longer wait for 502 error, nothing else changes.

Here's the log:

```
Mar 21 23:13:46 ip-172-31-35-104 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: Unit nginx.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 21 23:13:46 ip-172-31-35-104 sudo[2107]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 21 23:14:19 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[2055]: [2019-03-21 23:14:19 +0000] [2055] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:2061)
Mar 21 23:14:19 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[2055]: [2019-03-21 23:14:19 +0000] [2061] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 2061)
Mar 21 23:14:19 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[2055]: base dir path /home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel
Mar 21 23:14:19 ip-172-31-35-104 gunicorn[2055]: [2019-03-21 23:14:19 +0000] [2125] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2125
```

nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name puchalatravel.com www.puchalatravel.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://puchalatravel.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name puchalatravel.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/puchalatravel.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/puchalatravel.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; #managed by Certbot

    location /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/;
    }

    location /media {
        root /home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        root /var/www/common/letsencrypt/;
    }

    location / {
        # include proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        }
}
```

gunicorn setup:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravelenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --timeout 30 --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock puchalatravel.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

No changes at all were made in Django code except for adding the following lines in settings.py:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

All the code can be found here: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/michalpuchala/puchalatravel)
Website address: [puchalatravel.com](https://puchalatravel.com)

Any ideas what could be the source of the issue?

EDIT. Looks like an issue with SSL, nginx error log:

```
2019/03/22 07:15:24 [error] 2123#2123: *83 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 83.6.170.100, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "puchal$2019/03/22 07:15:56 [error] 2123#2123: *85 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 83.6.170.100, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/favic$2019/03/22 07:36:35 [error] 2123#2123: *94 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "puc$2019/03/22 07:37:06 [error] 2123#2123: *94 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/fa$2019/03/22 07:40:58 [error] 2123#2123: *100 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "pu$2019/03/22 07:41:29 [error] 2123#2123: *100 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/f$2019/03/22 07:44:22 [error] 12508#12508: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "pu$2019/03/22 07:44:52 [error] 12508#12508: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/f$2019/03/22 07:53:57 [error] 12508#12508: *4 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "pu$2019/03/22 07:54:10 [notice] 12698#12698: signal process started
2019/03/22 07:54:24 [notice] 12700#12700: signal process started
2019/03/22 07:54:27 [notice] 12703#12703: signal process started
2019/03/22 07:54:28 [error] 12508#12508: *4 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/f$2019/03/22 07:58:51 [error] 12704#12704: *27 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 5.255.250.163, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/rob$2019/03/22 07:59:22 [error] 12704#12704: *30 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 141.8.143.160, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/rob$2019/03/22 07:59:53 [error] 12704#12704: *32 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 178.154.246.138, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /posts/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/posts$2019/03/22 08:03:10 [error] 12813#12813: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "pu$2019/03/22 08:03:41 [error] 12813#12813: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/f$2019/03/22 08:37:39 [error] 12813#12813: *18 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "p$2019/03/22 08:56:08 [error] 13024#13024: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/", host: "pu$2019/03/22 08:56:39 [error] 13024#13024: *1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 213.229.174.164, server: puchalatravel.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock:/f$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with this line in nginx config:

```
proxy_pass https://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock;
```

The fix is to change **https** to **http**.

Full nginx config in the end:

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    listen                  [::]:80;
    server_name             puchalatravel.com www.puchalatravel.com;

    return                  301 https://puchalatravel.com;
}

server {

    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             puchalatravel.com;

    access_log              /var/log/nginx/puchalatravel.com.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/puchalatravel.com.error.log;

    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/puchalatravel.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/puchalatravel.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:5m;
    include                 /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; #managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam             /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; #managed by Certbot

    location /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/;
    }

    location /media {
        root /home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        root /var/www/common/letsencrypt/;
    }

    location / {
        # include proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect              off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name       on;
        proxy_ssl_certificate       /etc/letsencrypt/live/puchalatravel.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key   /etc/letsencrypt/live/puchalatravel.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass                  http://unix:/home/ubuntu/puchalatravel/puchalatravel.sock;
        proxy_set_header            Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout       60s;
        proxy_read_timeout          120s;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! you saved my day. It gets changed automatically with `Certbot`